# Calling WCF SOAP service with service reference .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wcf, soap

Calling WCF service with .NET Core version 3.1
ends up with this exception

> "The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).
> If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: '"

With both configurations

```
var x = new ServiceSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration.ServiceSoap);
var y = new ServiceSoapClient(ServiceReference1.ServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.ServiceSoap12)
```

It looks like I need to change the generated `GetBindingForEndpoint` function

How do I change the binding to text/HTML?

Comment: What binding are you using? Some bindings in WCF are not supported in core: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/release-notes/SupportedFeatures-v2.0.0.md

Comment: i tried with the 2 defalut bindings that .net core add  basichttpbinding and CustomBinding with TextMessageEncodingBindingElement